# Using Properties with Validation. Different types of Property and values to check

Tags: c#, validation, properties, console-application

I have the class DT. I need validate the field's value ("date": method "set") before assigning. I want to compare field initialisation's date and 01.01.2018. I want to have a "string" type argument in DT. How can I do it? I must create a new method?

```
public class DT
{
    private string data;        

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Data
    {
        get
        {
            return data;
        }
        set
        {                
            data = value;                
        }
    }

    public DT(string name, string data)
    {
        Name = name;
        Data = data;
    }
}
```

If I took:

```
if(DateTime.Parse(data) < DateTime.Parse("01.01.2018"))
......
```

I got System.ArgumentNullException Error...

Comment: Posting the actual code you're seeing the issue in would help, additionally any more info from the exception (like where it's occurring). 

I'd suggest running the code in debug mode and see where the exception is being thrown, look at what is null that's causing the issue, then try to back track through the code to see why it is null.

Comment: Thank you! I'll certainly use your advice in my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can have that check in the property's `set`.  You'd want to do something akin to

```
public string Data
{
    get
    {
        return data;
    }
    set
    {                
        if(DateTime.Parse(value) < DateTime.Parse("01.01.2018"))
            data = value;      
    }
}
```

My guess is that `data` is null in the `if` snippet you posted.

As a suggestion, I'd make the property a `DateTime` instead of just a `string` if this field is always a `DateTime`.  Gives you a little extra type checking as opposed to having to make sure the `string` is in the correct format.  Also if someone attempts to set `Data` to a `string` that can't be parsed as a `DateTime` it will throw an exception right now, which is another reason to make the field a `DateTime.

Comment: Thank you very much! You indicated my syntax error - now I'll be attentional. Use "string" type - the requirement of technical specification.